# VBA OR IF Statement

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the OR operator so that my function says " if the cell doesn't start with 'rw-promo' or 'rw-content' then delete the entire row.

However, the function is not considering 'rw-content' so I am left with the cells the start with 'rw-promo'.

Any help is appreciated!

---

```
Sub monthly_delete_emails()

    'Disab;e certain Excel features, whilst the macro is running'
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

        'Declare variables'
        Dim deleteRow As Long
        Dim ws As Worksheet

        'Set objects'
        Set ws = ActiveSheet

         'Loop through the rows of data, in order to delete rows with'
         'a value in column B. Our macro starts at row 9'
         For deleteRow = ws.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row To 9 Step -1

             'identify values in col B, which start with ___'
             If Not ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-promo*" Or ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-content*" Then
                 Rows(deleteRow).EntireRow.delete
             End If

         'Move to next cell in the range, which is being looped'
         Next deleteRow

    'Re-enable the above Excel features, which were disables whilst the macro ran'
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: You need to either add parens or another `Not`.  [`Not` has higher precedence than `Or`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/operator-precedence).

Comment: Like: `If Not (ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-promo*" Or ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-content*") Then`  In short: `If Not(cond1 OR cond2) Then`  Or you could also do `If Not cond1 AND Not cond2 Then`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the 'Not' operator does not apply to both of your statements. It appears that way as an English statement, but does not execute that way as a VBA conditional. What your posted code is saying is: "If the cell doesn't start with rw-Promo or if the cell starts with rw-content, delete the cell".What you need is that line to read:

```
If Not ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-promo*" Or Not ws.Range("B" & deleteRow).Value Like "rw-content*" Then
```

The same kind of thing trips people up all over any programming language.